# MOQ: Throwing exception that was passed into a method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method on an interface:

```cs
void HandleError(MyClasss c, object o, Exception e);
```

I want to mock this with MOQ, and on any parameters throwing the supplied Exception e.

Something like:

```cs
_mock.Setup(a => a.HandlreError(It.IsAny<MyClass>(), It.IsAny<object>()
   , It.IsAny<Exception>())).Throws( [the 'any' exception] )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a *callback* action which is invoked with parameters passed to mocked object:

```
_mock
.Setup(a => a.HandlreError(It.IsAny<MyClass>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<Exception>()))
.Callback((MyClass c, object o, Exception e) => { throw e; });
```

Comment: @Nkosi action will be invoked during mock MethodCall execution, in the same place where exception from `Throws` is thrown